# Can PCs create a Mob?

Tags: combat, numenera

We are in a situation where we are facing off against a large force of Margr. Around 50 of them. Now, having fought them before, they seem to rely on mob tactics. Basically, when in a mob, it acts as a single entity:

> To make things easier, the GM can take any creature and have a group of six to ten of them attack en masse as a single creature that is two levels higher, inflicting double the original creature’s normal damage.

Since there are 6 of us, is it possible for the Party (PCs and any other willing NPCs) to do the same?

Comment: Part of our [fine cheese collection](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7218/23970).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, they cannot.

> Combats in Numenera move quickly enough that a GM should not hesitate to use large groups of creatures as challenges for PCs, particularly powerful PCs. A screaming, squirming horde of thirty abhumans is a possible encounter. A swarm of fifty laaks could also be used.
>
> To make things easier, **the GM can take any creature and have a group of six to ten of them attack en masse as a single creature** that is two levels higher, inflicting double the original creature’s normal damage. So thirty level 3 abhumans might attack as five level 5 mobs.

**No**. You are six individuals with different stats, weapons and damage, because the rules for mob requires that the *grouped creatures* to be the same type. You cannot combine different creatures into a mob then take the highest or lowest damage between them to apply.

And again, because it says *the GM can*, not that *the players can*. So allowing this or not is completely within the GM's hands. But you will have trouble figuring the attack rolls and damage done.

**Yes**, if all six of you are exact copies of each other (can be done with artifacts). However, this requires GM permission, as the mob rules (quoted above) are within a GM-only chapter (*creatures*)..

**Yes**, if you, as an individual character, somehow obtained control of a group of creatures (also possible with artifacts), you could control them as a mob with GM permission.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of behavior robs users of their individual roleplaying ability and I would discourage it. It sounds an awful lot like a hacky attempt to get a stat boost.

If there is a valid need for simplifying player control, many flavors of mass-combat rules exist. I would not use the mob rule.